# GHEX Snap removal has left behind a 52MB Volume Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: uninstall, snap, software-uninstall

I very recently downloaded GHex from Ubuntu Software, but I realised it was the SNAP version that doesn't operate on files outside out of its sandbox.

So I un-installed it using the "uninstall" option on the Ubuntu Software site, however I seem to be left with a new Volume on my hard disk, mounted in `/media/alan/disk`, which contains the following files and directories:

```
Wed Nov 22 17:36 /media/alan/disk => ls -al
total 9
drwxrwxr-x    7    root root    131  Jun 14  2016 .
drwxrwxrwx+   3    root root   4096   Nov 22 17:17 ..
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  458 Jun 14  2016 command-ghex.wrapper
drwxrwxr-x  6 root root   94 Jun 14  2016 etc
-rwxrwxr-x  1 root root 3770 Jun 13  2016 ghex.wrapper
drwxrwxr-x  3 root root   39 Jun 14  2016 lib
drwxrwxr-x  3 root root   43 Jun 14  2016 meta
drwxrwxr-x  7 root root  101 Jun 14  2016 usr
drwxrwxr-x  3 root root   26 Jun 14  2016 var
```

The Volume is called "52MB Volume", and is sized at approximately 171 MB.

Please can someone tell me the safe way to remove this hangover?

Answer (score 0):

I had these after removing snaps.  They went away for me on a reboot, but I have yet to find a way to clear them while running.